# Big Hero 6: Abigal Callaghan

Tags: big-hero-6

When Baymax and Hiro find Abigal in the portal she is in deep sleep. She's been there for years so how did she not die of hunger?

Comment: Is this in the TV series or the movie?

Comment: Because she was in hyper-sleep